# GCC placing register args on the stack with a gap below local variables?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, compiler-optimization

I tried to look at the assembly code for a very simple program.

```
int func(int x) {
    int z = 1337;
    return z;
}
```

With GCC -O0, every C variable has a memory address that's not optimized away, so gcc spills its register arg:  ([Godbolt, gcc5.5 -O0 -fverbose-asm](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'int+func(int+x)+%7B%0A++++int+z+%3D+1337%3B%0A++++return+z%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:46.096920342406875,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g550,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O0+-fverbose-asm',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+5.5+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:53.90307965759314,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4))

```
func:
        pushq   %rbp  #
        movq    %rsp, %rbp      #,
        movl    %edi, -20(%rbp) # x, x
        movl    $1337, -4(%rbp) #, z
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax  # z, D.2332
        popq    %rbp    #
        ret
```

What is the reason that the function parameter x gets placed on the stack below the local variables?  Why not place it at at `-4(%rbp)` and the local below that?

And when placing it below the local variables, why not place it at `-8(%rbp)`?

Why leave a gap, using more of the [red-zone](/questions/tagged/red-zone) than necessary?  Couldn't this touch a new cache line that wouldn't otherwise have been touched in this leaf function?

Comment: `x` is being passed to the function in the register `%edi`, not on the stack.  The compiler is creating "local" space on the stack to store it (since it's not used, a higher optimization level would likely omit it entirely).

Comment: How can you tell that `x` is below the stack??  It would be the caller that passes `x`. 
 By the C code, the callee doesn't ever touch `x`.

Comment: "Why not place it at `-4(%rbp)`?" Sure, why not. But then somebody else would ask, "Why not place it at `-20(%rbp)`?" It doesn't matter where it gets placed.

Comment: It will be placed where the [calling convention](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Calling_Conventions) says it will be placed.

Comment: @WeatherVane: No, here it has nothing to do with calling convention. The calling convention governs how the value arrives to the function, not where the function stores the local variable corresponding to it.

Comment: You disabled optimisations.  Clearly, the compiler won't make optimal choices this way.

Comment: @JohnBode I know that `x` is passed in the `%edi` register. But why save it further down the stack later than really necessary?

Comment: In this [answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/14883) on Reverse Engineering there is the paragraph *However, on i386 architecture systems, GCC aligns the stack to a 16-byte boundary by default: This means that the compiler allocates 16 bytes of space on the stack frame for variables whose type sizes are less than 16 bytes. For example, even though an int is 4 bytes on an i386 system, the compiler would still allocate 16 bytes of space on the stack frame for it.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(First of all, don't expect efficient decisions at `-O0`.  It turns out that the things you noticed at `-O0` still happen at `-O3` if we use `volatile` or other things to force the compiler to allocate stack space otherwise this question would be a lot less interesting.)

> What is the reason that the function parameter x gets placed on the stack below the local variables?

The choice is 100% arbitrary, and depends on compiler internals.  GCC and clang both happen to make that choice, but it's basically irrelevant.  The args arrive in registers and basically *are* just locals so it's totally up to the compiler to decide where to spill them (or not spill at all, if you enable optimization).

- [Order of local variable allocation on the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102049/order-of-local-variable-allocation-on-the-stack) links  ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/summit/2003/Optimal%20Stack%20Slot%20Assignment.pdf

> But why save it further down the stack later than really necessary?

**Because of known(?) GCC missed-optimization bugs leading to wasting stack space.**  For example, [Why does GCC allocate more space than necessary on the stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63009070/why-allocate-more-than-necessary-on-stack) demonstrates x86-64 GCC `-O3` allocating 24 instead of 8 bytes of stack space, where clang allocates 8.  (I think I've seen a bug report about sometimes using an extra 16 bytes of space when GCC needs to move RSP (unlike here where it's just using the red zone) but can't find it on the GCC bugzilla.)

Note that the x86-64 System V ABI mandates 16-byte stack alignment before `call`.  After `push %rbp` and setting up RBP as a frame pointer, RBP and RSP are 16-byte aligned.  `-20(%rbp)` is in the same aligned 16-byte chunk of stack space as `-8(%rbp)` so this gap isn't risking touching a new cache line or page that we wouldn't already have touched.  (A naturally-aligned chunk of memory can't cross any boundary wider than itself, and x86-64 cache lines are always at least 32 bytes; these days always 64 bytes.)

However, this *does* become a missed optimization if we add a 2nd arg, `int y`: gcc5.5 (and current gcc9.2 -O0) spills it to `-24(%rbp)` which could be in a new cache line.

---

It turns out this missed optimization is *not* just because you used `-O0` (compile fast, skip most optimization passes, [make bad asm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366394/why-does-clang-produce-inefficient-asm-with-o0-for-this-simple-floating-point)).  Finding missed optimizations in `-O0` output is meaningless unless they're still present at an optimization level anyone cares about, specifically `-Os`, `-O2` or `-O3`.

**We can prove it with code that uses `volatile` to still make gcc allocate stack space for args/locals at `-O3`**  Another option would have been to pass their address to another function, but then GCC would have to reserve space instead of just using the red-zone below RSP.

```
int *volatile sink;

int func(int x, int y) {
    sink = &x;
    sink = &y;
    int z = 1337;
    sink = &z;
    return z;
}
```

([**Godbolt**, gcc9.2](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:%27int+*volatile+sink%3B%0A%0Aint+func(int+x,+int+y)+%7B%0A++++sink+%3D+%26x%3B%0A++++sink+%3D+%26y%3B%0A++++int+z+%3D+1337%3B%0A++++sink+%3D+%26z%3B%0A++++return+z%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:30.731280228271252,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%271%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-fverbose-asm%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:35.93538643839543,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang900,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%271%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-fverbose-asm%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+9.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4))

```
gcc9.2 -O3  (hand-edited comments)
func(int, int):
        leaq    -20(%rsp), %rax                 # &x
        movq    %rax, sink(%rip)        # tmp84, sink
        leaq    -24(%rsp), %rax                 # &y
        movq    %rax, sink(%rip)        # tmp86, sink
        leaq    -4(%rsp), %rax                  # &z
        movq    %rax, sink(%rip)        # tmp88, sink
        movl    $1337, %eax     #,
        ret     
sink:
        .zero   8
```

Fun fact: clang -O3 spills the stack args before storing their address to `sink`, like it was a `std::atomic` release-store of the address and another thread could maybe load their value after getting the pointer from `sink`.  But it doesn't do that for `z`.  It's just a missed optimization to actually spill `x` and `y` and I can only speculate on what part of clang's internal machinery might be to blame.

Anyway, clang does allocate `z` at `-4(%rsp)`, `x` at -8, `y` at `-12`.  So for whatever reason, **clang also chooses to put the spill slots for the args below the locals.**

---

Related:

- [Waste in memory allocation for local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249788/waste-in-memory-allocation-for-local-variables) discusses GCC's `main` not assuming 16-byte alignment on entry to `main`.
- several possible duplicates about GCC allocating extra stack space for variables, but mostly just as required by alignment, not extra.