# Why is there an 8 byte offset for storing an integer?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, lldb

I am trying to learn assembly, and I am following a guide from a book, and in this book the author disassembles a very simple C program and goes line by line through the assembly. I am doing the same, but I am getting slightly different results. I am using a different /debugger than the author (he is using gdb, I am using lldb), so I am sure that is causing a difference, but I am wondering if somebody could explain what the difference is in this example.

The C program we are analyzing is this:

```
main()
{
    int i; 
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        puts("Hello, world!");
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Here is *my* dissasembled code (I am using lldb)

```
a.out`main:
    0x100000f40 <+0>:  push   rbp
    0x100000f41 <+1>:  mov    rbp, rsp
    0x100000f44 <+4>:  sub    rsp, 0x10
    0x100000f48 <+8>:  mov    dword ptr [rbp - 0x4], 0x0
->  0x100000f4f <+15>: mov    dword ptr [rbp - 0x8], 0x0
    0x100000f56 <+22>: cmp    dword ptr [rbp - 0x8], 0xa
    0x100000f5a <+26>: jge    0x100000f7d               ; <+61> at firstprog.c
    0x100000f60 <+32>: lea    rdi, [rip + 0x3f]         ; "Hello, world!"
    0x100000f67 <+39>: call   0x100000f86               ; symbol stub for: puts
    0x100000f6c <+44>: mov    dword ptr [rbp - 0xc], eax
    0x100000f6f <+47>: mov    eax, dword ptr [rbp - 0x8]
    0x100000f72 <+50>: add    eax, 0x1
    0x100000f75 <+53>: mov    dword ptr [rbp - 0x8], eax
    0x100000f78 <+56>: jmp    0x100000f56               ; <+22> at firstprog.c:6:15
    0x100000f7d <+61>: xor    eax, eax
    0x100000f7f <+63>: add    rsp, 0x10
    0x100000f83 <+67>: pop    rbp
    0x100000f84 <+68>: ret
```

Why is the offset to `rbp` on the line where the arrow is `0x8`? In the example in the book it is only `0x4`, and I know I am about to store an `int`, so it makes sense it would be `0x4`. I see it also makes an offset for `0x4`, but why go on to the `0x8`? I am a bit of a beginner in assembly, so apologies if this is an obvious question.

Comment: If you could post the rest of the disassembly of the function, it might become clear what the code eventually does with the dword at `[rbp-0x4]`.  But it's probably just that your are using a different compiler (version, options, etc) than the book, and it happens to do things differently.  That's normal.

Comment: @NateEldredge thank you -- I updated the post. That makes sense that it would be different, I'm just wondering if anybody might know why it is offsetting the register by 8? 4 makes a lot of sense for int's obviously, but why would it offset by 8?

Comment: While it's unclear why the compiler is doing so from this code example, is seems that it has reserved `[rbp-0x4]` for something and is placing `i` in the next available position `[rbp-0x8]`

Comment: @Arkia I see -- so, we can assume it is using `[rbp-0x4]` for something else, but that our `i` int value is stored and manipulated at `[rbp-0x8]`?

Comment: @nickhealy That seems to be the case.

Comment: @Arkia that's a good insight, thank you

Comment: The difference is due to different compilers, rather than different debuggers. Your compiler seems to be `clang`. If your book has more examples of disassembled C programs, you should consider installing `gcc`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: or use Linux GCC on https://godbolt.org/.  Agreed, looks like the clang -O0 behaviour of [Why is 0 moved to stack when using return value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31149806)

Comment: Also related: [GCC placing register args on the stack with a gap below local variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58631698) re: the fact that stack layout is totally arbitrary.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to learn assembly - do not learn from `-O0` (no optimization) assembly output.

With optimizations on the assembly, the output is much more logical:

```
.LC0:
        .string "Hello, world!"
main:
        push    rbx
        mov     ebx, 10
.L2:
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    puts
        sub     ebx, 1
        jne     .L2
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rbx
        ret
```