# Why does scanf() appear to load an address lower than that of the buffer I am writing to?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, buffer-overflow

I wrote a C program with an intentional buffer overflow for a class assignment. In my program, I have a main function to accept a name from the user as a character array of length 50. The name is then passed as a character array of length 50, where the message `"Hello, user!"`  is printed. User is replaced with the name provided by the user.  I do not do any length checking on the `scanf()` function, but instead get input until a new line character is encountered. As a result, I am able to overrun the buffer, overwrite the return address of main and cause a segmentation fault.

When I disassemble `main`, using the GDB commands, I am able to see that the address `[ebp - 0x3a]` is loaded and pushed into the stack to be used as an argument for the `scanf` function (see photo below). I assumed that this is the start of the buffer, until I converted 0x3a to decimal and found out its value was 58. **Why would there be an additional 8 bytes allotted to the character buffer? Why when I try to run this buffer overflow, do only need 54 characters to overrun the buffer when it the buffer length appears to start 58 bytes away from ebp and 62 bytes away from the return address?** Again, I calculated the length to the return address by using `ebp-0x3a`.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void printHello(char fname[]);
int main() {
 
    char name[50]; 
    printf("Please enter a name to print a hello message!"); 
    scanf("%[^\n]", name); 

    printHello(name); 
    return 0;
}
void printHello(char fname[50]){

    int strLen = strlen(fname);

    printf("Hello, ");
    for(int i=0; i<strLen; i++){

        printf("%c", fname[i]);
     }
       printf("!\n");
}
```

Disassembled `main` function:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x080484fb <+0>: lea    ecx,[esp+0x4]
   0x080484ff <+4>: and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x08048502 <+7>: push   DWORD PTR [ecx-0x4]
   0x08048505 <+10>:    push   ebp
   0x08048506 <+11>:    mov    ebp,esp
   0x08048508 <+13>:    push   ecx
   0x08048509 <+14>:    sub    esp,0x44
   0x0804850c <+17>:    sub    esp,0xc
   0x0804850f <+20>:    push   0x8048640
   0x08048514 <+25>:    call   0x8048390 <printf@plt>
   0x08048519 <+30>:    add    esp,0x10
   0x0804851c <+33>:    sub    esp,0x8
   0x0804851f <+36>:    lea    eax,[ebp-0x3a]
   0x08048522 <+39>:    push   eax
   0x08048523 <+40>:    push   0x804866e
   0x08048528 <+45>:    call   0x80483e0 <__isoc99_scanf@plt>
   0x0804852d <+50>:    add    esp,0x10
   0x08048530 <+53>:    sub    esp,0xc
   0x08048533 <+56>:    lea    eax,[ebp-0x3a]
   0x08048536 <+59>:    push   eax
   0x08048537 <+60>:    call   0x804854c <printHello>
   0x0804853c <+65>:    add    esp,0x10
   0x0804853f <+68>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x08048544 <+73>:    mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
   0x08048547 <+76>:    leave  
   0x08048548 <+77>:    lea    esp,[ecx-0x4]
   0x0804854b <+80>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: Unrelated, a clang disassembly of this in -O2 optimization did something I found remarkable. The for-loop with `printf` internal was optimized to use `putchar` instead. I did *not* see that coming. [See it here](https://godbolt.org/z/nG3n1T).

Comment: Note you don't need to overwrite the return address, it's enough if you overwrite `[ebp-0x4]` (54 bytes away) which will eventually end up in `esp` and thus cause a crash.

Comment: `ebp-0x3a` is the address of `name`. The additional 8 bytes are the rest of the stack frame, which is where ebp is pushed.

Comment: @WhozCraig : Most modern GCC and CLANG will do the same thing with printf and resolve it down to a `puts` or `putchar` if it can. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36343733/o2-optimizes-printfs-n-str-to-putsstr

Comment: Also, gcc handles `main` specially with the stack alignment code. A normal function would look different.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Wow. thanks for the link, btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I assumed that this is the start of the buffer, until I converted 0x3a to decimal and found out its value was 58.

That *is* the start of the buffer, but why would you assume that it should be at a particular offset from `ebp`? There is no written rule that says that a function should have a stack exactly the size of its local variables. A compiler is pretty much allowed to do whatever it wants. In fact, it could end up using more space in order to preserve register values, [maintain alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061818/stack-allocation-padding-and-alignment), or even just to waste it whenever it feels like so. This has been asked countless times, but unfortunately there really is no definitive answer, you might as well become a GCC developer to try and understand it :')

Here's some existing questions with excellent answers for reference:

- [Waste in memory allocation for local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249788/waste-in-memory-allocation-for-local-variables)
- [Why does GCC allocate more space than necessary on the stack, beyond what's needed for alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63009070/why-does-gcc-allocate-more-space-than-necessary-on-the-stack-beyond-whats-need)
- [GCC placing register args on the stack with a gap below local variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631698/gcc-placing-register-args-on-the-stack-with-a-gap-below-local-variables)

In addition to the above, you are compiling with no optimizations, as I can tell from nonsensical instructions like `add esp,0x10; sub esp,0x8`. GCC likes to move stuff back and fort to/from the stack when no optimizations are enabled, and also doesn't really take much care into managing stack space in the best way possible.

> Why when I try to run this buffer overflow, do only need 54 characters to overrun the buffer

You technically only need 50 characters of input to overrun the buffer (a terminating `\0` is automatically added by `scanf()`). However, those might not be enough to "break" anything.

To make this clearer, let's assume that initially when `main()` is called `esp` is `0x1000`. The stack layout at the moment of the call to `scanf()` (right before `call` is executed) should be the following if my math is right:

```
esp -> 0x0fac: 0x804866e // scanf() arg1
       0x0fb0: 0x0fbe    // scanf() arg2
       0x0fb4: ????
       0x0fb8: ????
       0x0fbc: ??AA <-- eax == 0x0fbe == ebp-0x3a
       0x0fc0: AAAA   
       0x0fc4: AAAA
       0x0fc8: AAAA
       0x0fcc: AAAA
       0x0fd0: AAAA
       0x0fd4: AAAA
       0x0fd8: AAAA
       0x0fdc: AAAA
       0x0fe0: AAAA
       0x0fe4: AAAA
       0x0fe8: AAAA
       0x0fec: AAAA
       0x0ff0: ????
       0x0ff4: 0x1004 // saved original esp+0x4, later used to restore esp
ebp -> 0x0ff8: <saved ebp>
       0x0ffc: ????
       0x1000: ????   // 0x1000 original esp at start of main()
       0x1004: ????
```

In the above diagram, the `A`s denote your array, which starts at `0x0fbe`.

You are most probably getting a segmentation fault exactly at 54 (+1 terminator = 55) because that is exactly the bare minimum needed to alter the saved `esp+0x4` value (in the example `0x1004`) and cause trouble later on when it's used to restore `esp` (`mov ecx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]; leave; lea esp,[ecx-0x4]`) ending up with an invalid stack pointer.